# How do you create parametric distribution?

Tags: statistics, maple

I'm trying to create Skewed Normal distribution with the following PDF

I'm using the following command for that (referenced from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution):

I'm trying to do the following:

**SkewedNormal := Distribution(PDF = unapply(2*phi(x, mu, sigma)*Phi(alpha*x, mu, sigma), x, mu, sigma, alpha))**

This command executes without errors, the same as the following command:

**R := RandomVariable(SkewNormal)**

but the problems start when I try to do the following:

**CDF(R,x)**

> Error, (in Statistics:-CDF) invalid input: q uses a 3rd argument, sigma, which is missing

Ok, I add the third parameter:

**CDF(R,x,y)**

> Error, (in Statistics:-CDF) unexpected parameters: y

If you try previously to init random variable the following way:

**R := RandomVariable(SkewNormal(mu, sigma))**

> Error, (in Statistics:-Distribution) invalid input: IsKnownDistribution expects its 1st argument, dn, to be of type

name, but received module () export Conditions, PDF, Type; option Distribution, Continuous; end module

How do you create parametric distribution in Maple 14?

Answer (score 2):

Can you not unapply with respect to only x? (Note you had a typo in the posted code, using SkewedNormal vs SkewNormal.)

```
with(Statistics):

SkewNormal := Distribution(PDF =
     unapply(2*phi(x, mu, sigma)*Phi(alpha*x, mu, sigma), x));

R := RandomVariable(SkewNormal):

CDF(R,x);
```

The final result there is an expression containing alpha, mu, and sigma. So `subs` or `eval` could then be used to instantiate at values for the parameters.

Comment: This is a false claim, "If it will have only one argument it won't be parametric". Expressions can contain names which are taken and treated usefully as parameters, which is precisely why I mentioned 2-argument `eval` (as one supporting aspect amongst many to choose from). If you think that only procedures and operators can be taken as having parameters then you are missing out on important bits of Maple's functionality.

Comment: I don't claim anything, I really appreciate your proposal, but It is not very comfortable to have parameters inside expression and performing `eval`s each time I need to set something, it is much more convenient to pass them to a function's parameter list, the way `Normal(alpha, beta)` distribution does it.

Comment: Regarding "This is false claim ..." I think that there several ways of understanding the fact of parametric-ness. One is understood in terms of expressions, i.e. "expression contains parameters then this is parametric expression". But also it is possible to understand the parametric-ness in functional terms, i.e. "expression is parametric if it accepts and promotes parameters". My question was related to functional terms, since creating parametric distribution in terms of expressions is a fairly straightforward task to do...

Answer (score 1):

In case anybody will face the same problem here's how I managed to solve it this way:

```
SkewedNormal := (xi, omega, alpha) ->
Distribution
(
    PDF = ((x) -> x*sqrt(2)*exp(-(1/2)*(x-xi)^2/omega^2)*(1/2+(1/2)*erf((1/2)*alpha*(x-xi)*sqrt(2)/omega))/(omega*sqrt(Pi))),
    CDF = (proc (x) local t; options operator, arrow; return 1/2+(1/2)*erf((1/2)*(x-xi)*sqrt(2)/omega)-(int(exp(-(1/2)*(t-xi)^2*(1+t^2)/omega^2)/(1+t^2), t = 0 .. alpha))/Pi end proc),
    Mean = xi+omega*alpha*sqrt(2/Pi)/sqrt(1+alpha^2),
    Variance = omega^2*(1-2*alpha^2/(sqrt(1+alpha^2)^2*Pi)),
    MGF = ((x) -> 2*exp(xi*x+(1/2)*omega^2*x^2)*(1/2+(1/2)*erf((1/2)*omega*alpha*x*sqrt(2)/sqrt(1+alpha^2))))
)
```

This way allows defining parametric distribution

Examples:

```
X:=SkewedNormal(u,v,m); # Skewed normal distribution with xi=u, omega=v, alpha=m

Y:=SkewedNormal(a,b,c); # Skewed normal distribution with xi=a, omega=b, alpha=c
```

It also works with functions from Statistics package, such as RandomVariable:

```
Rx:=RandomVariable(X);    
Ry:=RandomVariable(Y);
```

And calling:

```
CDF(Ry,x);
```

Gives

[image: Formula]